# Sklearn MultiLabelBinarizer() error when using for production

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Edit:
I have changed the code , from mlb to TfIdfVectorizer(). Still I am facing a problem. Please see below my code.

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
model = joblib.load('D:/Testing -Python/model_mlb.pkl')
new_input = 'How can I pay my Library Fees'
pred = model.predict(TfIdfVectorizer.transform([new_input]))
pred = mlb.inverse_transform(pred)
```

My model is as follows.

```
OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=SGDClassifier(alpha=0.001, average=False, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1,
   eta0=0.0, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15,
   learning_rate='optimal', loss='hinge', max_iter=5, n_iter=None,
   n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', power_t=0.5, random_state=42, shuffle=True,
   tol=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False),
      n_jobs=1)
```

When I am running this, getting error as

```
ValueError: X has 6 features per sample; expecting 1543
```

Just to inform

```
X_Train.shape = [555, 1543]
Y_Train.shape = [555, 57]
```

What is going wrong? Please help

**Further Edit (With Full Code):**
To train the model I am using a dataset whose sample is as follows

```
X                                     Y
How to resent my Password        ['Pass','ResetPass']
Where to See the next Road       ['Direction','NaN']
What is my next topic            ['Topic','Class']
Can I move without pass          ['Pass','MovePass']
```

The above dataset is in `pd.DataFrame()` .
Below is my code snippet

```
X = dataset['X']
Y = mlb.fit_transform(dataset['test_final'])
X_Train,X_Test,Y_Train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, random_state=0, test_size=0.33, shuffle=True)
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, random_state=42, max_iter=5, tol=None)))])
parameters = {'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
          'vect__max_df': [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0],
          'vect__smooth_idf': (True, False),
          'vect__sublinear_tf' : (True,False)}  
grid = GridSearchCV(text_clf, parameters, n_jobs=-1)   
fit = grid.fit(X_Train,Y_Train)
predict = grid.predict(X_Test)
predict_label = mlb.inverse_transform(predict)
joblib.dump(text_clf,'D:/Testing -Python/model_mlb.pkl')
```

Then I am applying the following codes for new X and trying to retrieve Y.

```
model= joblib.load('D:/Testing -Python/model_mlb.pkl')
new_input = 'How can I pay my Library Fees'
pred = model.predict([new_input])[0]
pred = mlb.inverse_transform(pred)
```

Running the above I am NOW getting the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Please help!!

Comment: When it says that you are providing only 18 features, this is because you are invoking the `.fit_transform()` method of an already fit labelbinarizer, if I understand correctly. This method refits the label binarizer, and its new output may not be acceptable by the already fit classifier. Try using the `.transform()` method of the Multilabel binarizer instead

Comment: @Daniel: I have changed the code as you suggested, still getting error

Comment: Initially you transform your training data set into 1543 element vector using `fit_transform` on `MultiLabelBinarizer`; you need to save trained MLB also as a part of the model and use it on new data, to transform it into 1543 element vector format.

Comment: @hellpanderr: so r u suggesting 'pipeline' method and then save the model as whole?

Comment: The error almost certainly is the one me and hellpanderr suggested, please post the full code and a mock dataset so we can correct it

Comment: @pythondumb yes

Comment: I see also that the file with your model is called `model_mlb.pkl`, so chances are that there is a multilabel binarizer already in your model, and you are instantiating a new multilabel binarizer instead of using the one you already trained.

Comment: @Daniel: Not exactly. The file contains the pipeline where TfIdfVectorizer() and Model is stored. I have posted the full code.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you are not saving any model on your path. Let's forget the `GridSearch` here

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['How to resent my Password',
                              'Where to See the next Road',
                              'What is my next topic',
                              'Can I move without pass']*10, 
                        'Y': [['Pass','ResetPass'], ['Direction','NaN'], ['Topic','Class'], ['Pass','MovePass']]*10})

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
X, Y = dataset['X'], mlb.fit_transform(dataset['Y'])
X_Train, X_Test, Y_Train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0, test_size=0.33, shuffle=True)

clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', 
                    alpha=1e-3, random_state=42, 
                    max_iter=5, tol=None)
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer()), 
                     ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(clf))])

text_clf.fit(X, Y) ### new line here
predict = text_clf.predict(X_Test)
predict_label = mlb.inverse_transform(predict)

joblib.dump(text_clf, 'PATHTO/model_mlb.pkl') #save the good model
joblib.dump(mlb, 'PATHTO/mlb.pkl') # save the MLB

model = joblib.load('PATHTO/model_mlb.pkl')
mlb = joblib.load('PATHTO/mlb.pkl') # load the MLB
new_input = 'How to resent my Password'
pred = model.predict([new_input]) ## tfidf in your pipeline
pred = mlb.inverse_transform(pred)
```

And this returns

```
[('Pass', 'ResetPass')]
```

as in your train test

And if you want your grid search to be save just save the `fit` (`= grid.fit()`)

Comment: Thanks J. Doe. Just a quick question! Can I tokenize and perform regex before vectorize?

Comment: you are free to do what you want ! perform your text cleaning before the tfidf vectorizer

Comment: Thanks J. Doe. Also in ''Y': [['Pass','ResetPass'], ['Direction','NaN'], ['Topic','Class'], ['Pass','MovePass']]*10}' what is this *10. And finally, instead of using X_Trainand Y_Train in 'fit', why you are using whole X and Y?

Comment: `[[1, 1]]*2 =  [[1, 1], [1, 1]]` so the `*10` just duplicates the dataset to have more items. Once in production, with a 'good' model, generally perform predictions with all your dataset to keep all information. Please accept edited answer if it solved your question :)

Comment: Getting an error: 'NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted'.

Comment: @J Doe: Yes I have used your solution only.

Comment: it is working on my desk .. which line fails ? copy/paste the edited answer

Comment: @J Doe: My Bad!! It worked. However while using 'pred=mlb.inverse_transform(pred)' I am getting (with a question "'How to resent my Password') [(' ', "'", ',', 'R', '[', ']', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't')].

Comment: what did you change in the script ? just use the last answer and it should work !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182158/discussion-between-pythondumb-and-j-doe).

Comment: The above solution is not working when I use pd.read_csv() method.